# BeagleBone Black not detected in network interface on Mac

Tags: ssh, osx-mavericks, beagleboard, beagleboneblack, network-interface

I have a BeagleBone Black development board. When I initially bought it, I set it up on my Mac and was able to ssh into it without any problem. Then, I followed a tutorial once for sharing the internet of my Mac with the BeagleBone using USB and since then I was unable to SSH into my BeagleBone from my Mac. I tried updating the HornDis driver and it didn't solve anything.

What happens is that my Mac (Mavericks) detects the BeagleBone drive, but it doesn't show up in the network interface. Hence, I can't ssh into the BeagleBone at all. I tried installing both the FTDI and HornDis driver over and over and it didn't solve the problem.

I really need it to work on my Mac and I'm kind of lost at this point. Any help would be really appreciated. I can't reinstall the OS in the BeagleBone because I have some very important project work installed and working in that BeagleBone and don't want to reinstall all those packages again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by resetting the SMC and the PRAM. Here are the details if someone needs it:

Reset the SMC and PRAM

**SMC Reset:**

- Shut down the MacBook Pro.
- Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if it's not already connected.
- On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
- Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
- Press the power button to turn on the computer.

**PRAM:**

- Shut down the MacBook Pro.
- Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command, Option, P, and R.
- Turn on the computer.
- Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
- Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
- Release the keys.

After following the above two steps I plugged in the BeagleBone and it was detected in the network interface. I was then able to successfully ssh into it.